# Manifest merger failed How to fix

Tags: android, manifest

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.
```

How fix this error..

Comment: You can't use androidx and support libraries together.

Comment: how to use androidx

Comment: Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Answer (score 0):

1. gradel file

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
   apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

   android {
       compileSdkVersion 29
       buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
       defaultConfig {
           applicationId "com.niks.abc"
           minSdkVersion 15
           targetSdkVersion 29
           versionCode 1
           versionName "1.0"
           testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled false
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
       }
       compileOptions {
          sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
           targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
   }

   dependencies {
       implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.50"
       implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
       implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
       implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
       testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
       androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
       androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
   }
   ```
2. Don't forget to add

   ```
   android.useAndroidX=true
   android.enableJetifier=true
   ```

   to your gradle.properties. I always forget this when I get on a new machine because gradle.properties is not in source control. Would be great if we got a sensible error in this case.
3. Manifest:

   ```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           package="com.niks.abc">

           <application
               android:allowBackup="true"
               android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
               android:label="@string/app_name"
               android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
               android:supportsRtl="true"
               android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
               <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                   <intent-filter>
                       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                   </intent-filter>
               </activity>
           </application>

       </manifest>
   ```

Hope this will help you enough.